# Is there an identity for the determinant of the sum of positive definite or semidefinite matrices?

Tags: matrices, determinant, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

I am familiar with the Minkowski inequality, but that is only for two matrices. What about three? four? Or in general, the determinant of the sum of matrices. Specifically positive definite or semidefinite matrices.